# Chart js footer

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to add a footer to chart js with a description of the chart. So far I got the plugin which is adding the text to the canvas. Now the problem is I can't extend the canvas height to fit in the description. It should add some space under the chart for description without changing the height of chart itself. My plugin is:

```
    beforeDraw: function (chart) {
    var height = chart.chart.height,
    ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.font = "1em sans-serif";
    ctx.fillText("chart description chart description chart description", 20, height -10); //-10 added so decription is visible at all
    ctx.save();
}
```

It looks like:

[image]

So as you can see the description is in same line as x label. If I add to height description is not visible at all. How can I change height of canvas that will add space for description? If I change just the height of canvas it will extend chart as well.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Basically, I'm adding padding in BeforeInit and then add description in BeforeDraw (only the essence here):

```
beforeInit: function (chart, options) {
    let isPieOrDoughnut = chart.config.type === 'pie' || chart.config.type === 'doughnut';
    if (isPieOrDoughnut) {
        chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.lineWidth = 0;
        chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = true;
    }

    chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].scaleLabel.padding.bottom = 50;
},
beforeDraw: function (chart, options) {
    ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.font = "1em sans-serif";
    let height = chart.chart.height;
    ctx.fillText('description', 30, height - 35);
    ctx.save();
}
```